# Error while using audioencoder library in an vue3 app

Tags: vuejs3

I need to use audioEncoder library in a Vue3 app.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-encoder

I installed audioEncoder using "npm install audio-encoder"

I see the library under the "node_modules"

I am able to import this as:

```
import { audioEncoder } from "audio-encoder";
```

The following line gives an error:

```
    const ae = new audioEncoder();
    ae.encode(audioBuffer, 128, null, function onComplete(blob) {
      console.log(blob);
    });
```

The error message is:
audioEncoder is not a constructor

I also tried:

```
    audioEncoder.encode(audioBuffer, 128, null, function onComplete(blob) {
      console.log(blob);
    });
```

this gives the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')

Any recommendations on what's the best way to use this library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the example code from the npm page.  This code will "work":

```js
<script setup>
import audioEncoder from 'audio-encoder';

// create audioBuffer
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const length = 44100; // one second @ 44.1KHz
const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, length, 44100);
const channelData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);

// fill some audio
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  channelData[i] = Math.sin(i * 0.03);
}

// convert as mp3 and save file using file-saver
audioEncoder(audioBuffer, 128, null, function onComplete(blob) {
  fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'sound.mp3');
});
</script>
```

I say "work" in quotations because it seems it *would* work if it wasn't for a known issue with the library reported [here](https://github.com/cstoquer/audio-encoder/issues/14)

In my opinion this library seems broken and does not look to be supported by it's author anymore.  I would suggest looking for a new library, preferably one that advertises itself as Vue compatible if you can.

Comment: Thanks! I used lamejs and ran into the issue that you mention above. Looks like audio-encoder uses the same underlying library.

Comment: Accepting your response since the syntax works. 

What’s the difference in import {abc} and import abc.

Comment: the syntax to use depends on how the thing you're importing was originally exported.  there are [two types of exports and imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description) "named" (require curly braces when importing) and "default" (no curly braces).